# How to properly format my UserData in a Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created some UserData that works perfectly when I launch a new EC2 instance. What I'm trying to do now is put this all in a Cloud Formation Template to make it easier to deploy. The UserData section is giving me the following error when I try to validate it in the designer.

Template contains errors.: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [PUBLICHOSTNAME] in the Resources block of the template

Here is my template that I'm trying to get working. Could I please get some advice on how to properly format this UserData.

Thank you very much!

```
Resources:
  Ec2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: *******
      InstanceType: r5a.xlarge
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref SSHSecurityGroup
        - !Ref ServerSecurityGroup
      KeyName: ********.pem
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: 
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash

            echo "Instance Boot Strapping Starting"

            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"

            echo "Setting vars"

            PUBLICHOSTNAME=$(curl -sL http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)

            echo "The public host name is ${PUBLICHOSTNAME}"

            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"

            echo "Starting Alation Services"

            sudo /etc/init.d/alation start

            echo "Alation Started"

            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"

            echo "Updating Alation Config"

            sudo chroot "/opt/alation/alation" /bin/su - alationadmin -c "alation_conf alation.install.base_url -s ${PUBLICHOSTNAME}"

            echo "Alation Config Updated"

            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"

            echo "Alation web:uwsgi restart"

            sudo chroot "/opt/alation/alation" /bin/su - alationadmin -c "alation_supervisor restart web:uwsgi"

            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"
            echo "**********"

            echo "Boot Strap Completed!"
  SSHSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
  ServerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via port 80
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I think all I needed to do was remove the {} from around the ${PUBLICHOSTNAME}. The template validated but I still just wanted to leave this question unanswered to see if anyone with more knowledge could look at it and confirm. I'm running tests now on the template to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

OK, it does seem like all I needed to do was remove those {} from around ${PUBLICHOSTNAME}.

I've run this cloud formation template and it worked. I'm sure there is a much better way to format this and there are some cool items I should have added but I'm still learning.